# Github pages are not generating

Tags: github-pages

The https://github.com/wolfv6/wfpb repository has four .org files:

- 1_wfpb_basics.org
- 2_wfpb_implementation.org
- 3_wfpb_advanced.org
- nutrition_confusion.org

I am attempting to publish the above four .org files using github pages.
I followed the "Project site" instructions on https://pages.github.com/.
The root index page renders as expected at https://wolfv6.github.io/wfpb/.

What are the URLs to the pages generated from the four .org files?
https://wolfv6.github.io/wfpb/1_wfpb_basics.html gets 404 File not found.

The video on https://pages.github.com/ shows two buttons that are missing from my Settings page:

- 2:38 "Launch automatic page generator" button is missing.
   Use the automatic page generator to create your first site.
   Guthub will populate your page with basic content that you can customize with markdown.
- 2:46 "Load README" button is missing.
   If your project already has a README file, you can you can import its content too.

Those two buttons in the video are not mentioned in the instructions.

Github renders the .org files nicely.  Can github pages render the same .org files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Automatic Page Generator" button was [retired some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41248716/cant-locate-automatic-page-generator-button-in-github/41249143), which is why it can't found in the current doco (unfortunately they haven't updated the video to match).

The same process can be kicked off by using the "Choose Theme" option in `Settings`, which then allows you to choose a theme and will [run Jekyll](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-github-pages-and-jekyll) in the background to generate your Github Pages site.

The bad new is that orgmode isn't a supported format - to generate that format would require [a plugin](https://github.com/tjaartvdwalt/jekyll-org-mode-converter) which isn't on the [supported list](https://pages.github.com/versions/). Only Markdown and HTML are supported out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

From https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/using-jekyll-as-a-static-site-generator-with-github-pages

The Automatic Page Generator is designed to create single page websites.

If you're interested in building a multi-page website, we recommend using Jekyll.